# Facebook FQL photo_tag table not returning all appropriate photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to run a query that returns all the latest tags that happened on my friends photos.

Here is my query:

```
String query = "SELECT subject, created FROM photo_tag WHERE subject IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 200";
```

This is supposed to return the latest 200 tags performed.

Unfortunately, after looking at my news feed, here are the first few results I get 
(formatted by SUBJECT at CREATED_TIME)

```
522274044 at Sun Sep 25 20:01:03 AEST 2011
522274044 at Sun Sep 25 20:00:26 AEST 2011
522274044 at Sun Sep 25 20:00:00 AEST 2011
522274044 at Sun Sep 25 20:00:00 AEST 2011
522274044 at Sun Sep 25 20:00:00 AEST 2011
522274044 at Sun Sep 25 20:00:00 AEST 2011
522274044 at Sun Sep 25 20:00:00 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 16:39:19 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 16:39:19 AEST 2011
522274044 at Sun Sep 25 15:00:04 AEST 2011
521342837 at Sun Sep 25 12:10:06 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 11:20:45 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 11:20:14 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 11:16:51 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 11:16:51 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 11:16:51 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 11:16:51 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 11:16:51 AEST 2011
521123280 at Sun Sep 25 11:16:51 AEST 2011
```

As you can see, there is a massive gap between 8PM and 4:39PM, and by checking my news feed, there are a WHOLE LOT of photos between these times that should be listed here. Is my FQL query correct? or does the facebook servers just not handle these kinds of queries.. Also, later down the list:

```
512328700 at Sun Jul 24 00:30:02 AEST 2011
523619736 at Sat Jul 23 17:36:37 AEST 2011
521342837 at Tue Jul 19 12:23:32 AEST 2011
519156948 at Fri Jul 15 15:08:11 AEST 2011
```

More massive inconsistencies.. Is there any explanation for this?? Thanks for your help!

UPDATE: Of all 200 results, I'm only retrieving about 10 unique subject names
UPDATE2: I tried querying a bunch of names that weren't in that list of 10 unique names above, and they resulted in the photos they were tagged in, concluding that their names aren't showing from the larger query above because of any 'privacy' settings or anything. So maybe it's a server side thing?

Comment: Just as a side comment -> I have people getting tagged on my feed at least twice an hour and usually more, so there should be alot of photos in between these gaps

Answer (score 1):

You will also want to make sure you have both user_photos and friends_photos permissions.  Also, friends can opt out of the Facebook platform so that their photos, etc are not available  to applications via the Facebook API:

[image]

Comment: I realise this is a year old but I was wondering if you can eliminate people with the platform disabled via an FQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Request denied: source address is sending an excessive volume of requests. hope your not recieving this while tag(photos)....i agree with facebook API:
0down vote

You will also want to make sure you have both user_photos and friends_photos permissions. Also, friends can opt out of the Facebook platform so that their photos, etc are not available to applications via the Facebook API: